# BeautifulSoup append() causes subsequent find() to fail

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Sometimes after appending a new element to a document, find() will fail. Specifically, if an append is made to the element being appended. The error happens if the 2nd element is appended to the first before the first is appended to the document. Here is an example of failure:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

import traceback
template = """
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
    </table>
    <p class="overview">
      Test
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
doc = BeautifulSoup(template, 'html.parser')

for row_count in range(2):
  row = doc.new_tag('tr', id=f'row_{row_count}')
  doc.find('table').append(row)
  
print(doc.find(id='row_0'), '\n')
cell = doc.new_tag('td',class_='item')
x = NavigableString('hi')
cell.contents.append(x)
doc.find(id='row_0').append(cell)
print(doc.find(id='row_1'), '\n')
print(doc.prettify())
```

My output for that is:

```
<tr id="row_0"></tr> 

None 

<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr id="row_0">
    <td class_="item">
     hi
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row_1">
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="overview">
   Test
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

It appears the solution is to ensure that appends are only made to elements that have already been appended to the document.

I am using bs4 version '4.8.2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call the append() function of the element, not of the contents of the element.

```
cell.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution is to ensure that appends are only made to elements that have already been appended to the document. Example:

```
import traceback
template = """
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
    </table>
    <p class="overview">
      Test
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
doc = BeautifulSoup(template, 'html.parser')

for row_count in range(2):
  row = doc.new_tag('tr', id=f'row_{row_count}')
  doc.find('table').append(row)
  
print(doc.find(id='row_0'), '\n')
cell = doc.new_tag('td',class_='item')
x = NavigableString('hi')
doc.find(id='row_0').append(cell)
cell.contents.append(x)
print(doc.find(id='row_1'), '\n')
print(doc.prettify())
```

output:

```
<tr id="row_0"></tr> 

<tr id="row_1"></tr> 

<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr id="row_0">
    <td class_="item">
     hi
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row_1">
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p class="overview">
   Test
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```